# Merging two dataframes that are differently structured

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Suppose I have two dataframes. They both vary in time and space, so they are panel data.

They are generated as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame("region" = c("Acre", "Espyrito Santo", "Amapah", "Goiahs"),
                  "time1" = c(1, 4, 5, 7),
                  "time2" = c(7, 4, 2, 6),
                  "time3" = c(5, 2, 5, 0))
```

```
df2 <- data.frame("region" = c("ACRE", "ACRE", "ACRE", 
                               "ESPIRITO SANTO","ESPIRITO SANTO","ESPIRITO SANTO",
                               "AMAPA","AMAPA","AMAPA", 
                               "GOIAS","GOIAS","GOIAS"),
                  "date" = c("time1", "time2", "time3", 
                             "time1", "time2", "time3", 
                             "time1", "time2", "time3", 
                             "time1", "time2", "time3"))
```

Here, you have the first panel, df1. Observe that region is a column related to space, so its values are name of specific locations. Time columns relate to a corresponding time period. In between, you have values relating to a variable, say: the number of murders (for the sake of illustration). So, for example, you have 1 murder at Acre at first time period (time1), and 7 murders at the subsequent time period (time2).

```
          region time1 time2 time3
1           Acre     1     7     5
2 Espyrito Santo     4     4     2
3         Amapah     5     2     5
4         Goiahs     7     6     0
```

Here, you have the second panel, df2. For the sake of simplicity, there is no variable in the strict sense. In this panel, you have the same regions, but they are written a bit differently. In this case, instead of having three columns relating to date, you have a single column where time periods are repeated.

```
           region  date
1            ACRE time1
2            ACRE time2
3            ACRE time3
4  ESPIRITO SANTO time1
5  ESPIRITO SANTO time2
6  ESPIRITO SANTO time3
7           AMAPA time1
8           AMAPA time2
9           AMAPA time3
10          GOIAS time1
11          GOIAS time2
12          GOIAS time3
```

What I'm trying to do is creating a new column on df2 called "murder". I want to distribute df1's values to this new column in df2. But I want to match such values with region and date.

For example, if I'm successful, the three first rows of df2 would look like this:

```
           region  date murder
1            ACRE time1      1
2            ACRE time2      7
3            ACRE time3      5
```

So, basically, I want to merge two panel data frames which are structured differently. They differ essentially in two ways: first, the regions are written a bit differently; and second, df1 is a 'wide' format dataframe while df2 is a 'long' format dataframe.

How do I merge them?

I didn't try anything, because I couldn't think of an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr` and `dplyr` functions

```
df1 %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-region, names_to = "date", values_to = "murder") %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(df2)
```

Comment: It returns the following error:

"Error in `dplyr::right_join()`:
! `by` must be supplied when `x` and `y` have no common
  variables.
ℹ Use `cross_join()` to perform a cross-join." .......................... I think I oversimplified my example. In the real database I'm working with, the corresponding "df2" already has some variables. I tried cross-join, but the regions aren't matching.

Comment: you have to have common names in both data frames e.g., region in df1 and df2

Comment: No I don't. As you can see in my example, the names are differently written. In df1, you have "Espyrito Santo" and in df2 you have "Espirito Santo". It's the same region, but they are written with a minor difference

Comment: there are 2 parts then. 1 - you need to have at least one column in each of the data frames with the same name so you have something to join on. 2 - you need to have the values that you are trying to match have the same spelling, or ignore the capitalization, can be accomplished using `stringr` a la `mutate(df2, region = str_to_title(region))`